# Spring Data ElasticSearch Can't Connect with ElasticSearch 5.5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Am new to ElasticSearch...

Really love the API (especially ElasticsearchTemplate & supporting Unit Tests)...

Was following this example using ElasticSearch 5.5.0 (the following link has the full code inline and also available as a downloadable zip file):

https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-spring-data-elasticsearch-example/

maven dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

EsConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.mkyong.book.repository")
public class EsConfig {

    @Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
    private String EsHost;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
    private int EsPort;

    @Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
    private String EsClusterName;

    @Bean
    public Client client() throws Exception {

        Settings esSettings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName)
                .build();

        //https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_transport_client_versus_node_client.html
        return TransportClient.builder()
                .settings(esSettings)
                .build()
                .addTransportAddress(
                  new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), EsPort));
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
    }
}
```

src/main/resources:

```
elasticsearch.clustername = mkyong-cluster
elasticsearch.host = localhost
elasticsearch.port = 9300
```

When issuing the following, either:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

or

```
mvn clean test
```

stdout:

```
Caused by: NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:326)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:223)
   at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.support.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:55)
```

Also, get the following in my ElasticSearch 5.5.0 engine's stdout:

```
[2017-07-23T02:48:46,135][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [vY7jxpr] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xa7e950be, L:/127.0.0.1:9300 - R:/127.0.0.1:60190]], closing connection
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [1.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1379) ~[elasticsearch-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.5.0.jar:5.5.0]
```

Is there any way to use Spring Data ElasticSearch with ElasticSearch 5.5.0 engine?

If so, how would the connection be implemented?

I am using the Elastic Search Java client provided by Elastic Search and am able to connect and create indices on ElasticSearch 5.5.0 but really wish I could use the power of this library.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot 1.5.1 does not support ElasticSearch 5.x (the article you provided also says it). To make it possible to work with ElasticSearch 5.x you need to use a milestone of Spring Boot 2.

Try to configure your project with following dependencies:

```
# spring boot
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.0.0.M2'

# elasticsearch
compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.5.0'
compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.5.0'

# spring-data-elasticsearch for spring boot
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:2.0.0.M2'
```

This should allow you to use all the goodies of Elasticsearch Java API ans spring-data-elasticsearch.

**Update:** Basic Gradle (v4.0.1) configuration would look like (*build.gradle* file):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
        maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar {
    baseName = 'elastic'
    version = '0.0.1'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
    maven { url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone/' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'

    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch'

    compile 'org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.4.1'
    compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.4.1'

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is good news but I don't know how to configure this with my Maven pom.xml... Also, I can't seem to find where in the article it mentioned Spring Boot 1.5.1 has lack of ElasticSearch 5.x. support.

Comment: At the beginning of the article there is a **Note** section:

`SpringBoot 1.5.1.RELEASE and Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.10.RELEASE supports only ElasticSearch 2.4.0. They don’t support the latest version of ElasticSearch 5.x version...`      I use mostly gradle for dependency management - I updated my answer with the configuration so it's easier to translate it to maven pom. I recomend https://start.spring.io/ for generating starter of pom file - it wil also generate the right repositories for milestones as they are not present in cental repository.